# alternative to range between interval for snowflake query

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to get an result from data where Desired Output is the last column in table below:

```
Customerid  txn_timestamp   txn_date    txn_id  Desired_Output
100     3/15/24 5:00 PM     15-Mar      100     12
100     3/15/24 4:00 PM     15-Mar      200     11
100     3/15/24 3:00 PM     15-Mar      300     10
100     3/15/24 2:00 PM     15-Mar      400      9
100     3/14/24 5:00 PM     14-Mar      500     10
100     3/14/24 4:00 PM     14-Mar      600      9
100     3/14/24 3:00 PM     14-Mar      700      8
100     3/14/24 2:00 PM     14-Mar      800      7
100     3/14/24 1:00 PM     14-Mar      900      6
100     3/14/24 12:00 PM    14-Mar      1000     5
100     3/13/24 5:00 PM     13-Mar      1100     7
100     3/13/24 4:00 PM     13-Mar      1200     6
100     3/12/24 5:00 PM     12-Mar      1300    
100     3/12/24 4:00 PM     12-Mar      1400    
100     3/11/24 5:00 PM     11-Mar      1500    
100     3/11/24 4:00 PM     11-Mar      1600    
100     3/11/24 3:00 PM     11-Mar      1700
```

Desired_Output Example: 1st record ie. 12 is calculated as count of txn_id between 13-Mar and 15-Mar ( 3Days transaction count including current row)

I tried using the logic, which does not work in SnowFlake:
count(txn_id) over (partition by Customerid order by txn_timestamp range between interval '2' DAY PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW) as calc

Also tried building logic using count(txn_id) over(partition by customerid, txn_dt order by txn_tms) but no success yet. May be using a sub-query will help

Update so far (used the query below):

```
select customerid, tran_id, count(*) 
from ( 
   Select a.* from tbl1 a 
   join tbl1 b 
       on a.customerid = b.customerid 
     and (b.tran_tms between date(a.txn_tms)-2 and a.txn_tms) 
   )
group by 1,2
```

Comment: Hi - a) please don’t use images, use editable text so someone can copy your data to try a solution b) add source table definitions and enough sample data to illustrate the use cases c) show the result you want to achieve based on the sample data d) show the complete SQL statement you’ve managed to write so far e) explain the issue/challenge you are facing

Comment: Do you want to count the transactions that occurred 3 days or less before each records transaction timestamp? If so, it would help if you clearly stated that in your question as it seems to be the single most important piece of information. Anyway, if that is the requirement then I’d solve it with a self join

Comment: Thanks NickW. Yes it would be 3days or less including the current row

Comment: select customerid, tran_id, count(*) from (
Select a.* from tbl1 a join tbl1 b on a.customerid = b.customerid and (b.tran_tms between date(a.txn_tms)-2 and a.txn_tms)
)group by 1,2

Answer (score 0):

This logic worked. i was beating my head around using window function. Thanks @NickW for suggestion.

```
select customerid, tran_id, count(*) 
from ( 
   Select a.* 
   from tbl1 a 
   join tbl1 b 
       on a.customerid = b.customerid 
     and (b.tran_tms between date(a.txn_tms)-2 and a.txn_tms) 
  )
group by 1,2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select t1.Customerid, t1.txn_timestamp, t1.txn_date, t1.txn_id, count(t2.txn_id)
From tbl1 t1
Left outer join tbl1 t2 on 
t1.txn_timestamp >= t2.txn_timestamp
And t2.txn_timestamp >= (t2.txn_timestamp - 2)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code answers the question will make it more useful for others in the future. Please consider updating your answer with some explanatory notes. Thanks

Comment: The questioner has already answered their own question. This SQL is just a better, IMO, way of writing that answer